# Creating a 100% width left, fixed width right, centered in container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a simple layout where it is filled width in the left div, with a max-width, and fixed width in the right div.

These divs are centered in a container.

If the max-width of the left div is hit, everything obviously works as intended. However, on a mobile phone, this functionality does not work as intended, and the left div would take up an entire row, forcing the right div onto a second line.

What is the correct way to solve this issue?

Here is the JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lozqg9ya/

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.right {
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.left {
  max-width: 1500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    Here we are
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Yeah
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want .right to take a fix width of 50px, .left to take as much as possible until 1500px and .container to take the rest. Is that correct? It's a bit odd to see two elements with 100%. I'm kind of sure that using calc() can fix your problem, but I want to make sure I understand your problem first.

Comment: Yes, so long as left and right are on the same line, and they are centered within that container. So for example ---LLLLLR---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use calc() on .left:

```
width: calc(100% - 50px - 8px);
```

The 100% is the default you wanted; 50px is substracting the .right size. The 8px is some borders, paddings, margins. Hence, I would also add padding: 0; and margin: 0; to your code.

Full code:

```
.container
{
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.right
{
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.left
{
  max-width: 1500px;
  width: calc(100% - 50px - 8px);
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

If you want to change any padding or magin, do not forget to increase the -8px;

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use flexbox as in the example below: The right column is not allowed to grow in width, the left has a percentage width (change taht as needed) and a max-width, both together are centered by `justify-content: center`

(Your 100% width for the left container was unclear to me: You want both centered, which would be irrelevant if the width were really 100%. Still , you can of course set it to 100% and only have the max-width limit)

```css
.container
{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
.right
{
  width:50px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.left
{
  max-width:1500px;
  width: 75%;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>

<p>Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.</p>

<p>Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi.</p>

<p>Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Yeah
  </div>
</div>
```

ADDED AFTER COMMENT:

Here is an additional solution with floats for older browsers. One essential thing is that you have to use the same background for container and right, since the right column won't extend across the whole height. Still, if your initial height is less than the window height, it won't fill the page and that will not look that good...

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #9cf;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 50px;
  background: #9cf;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  max-width: 1500px;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  background: #fc9;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
      quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>

    <p>Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean
      vulputate eleifend tellus.</p>

    <p>Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue.
      Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi.</p>

    <p>Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus.
      Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit
      cursus nunc,</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>Yeah</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great solution. Although I am worried that this would break significantly on browsers where flex is not supported

Comment: I added another solution using floats and `calc`

Comment: float would not be needed. You can keep using display: inline-block like in my answer.

Comment: yes, I also had that before, but for some reason the right element would never fill the remaining space inside container, also not if I used `box-sizing: border-box` on all elements. Also in your example the pure math would actually lead to a with of `calc(100% - 50px - 6px)`, for the 3 x 2 x 1 borders there are, but that won't work (also not with `margin: 0`  on `body` and `html`) - I don't know why... (maybe it's just a bug in the snippet creator)